# Graph theory question on degrees of vertices of a tree

Tags: graph-theory

Let $T$ be a tree with $n$ vertices and $p_i$ denote the number of vertices of degree $i$. Show that $$p_1-p_3-2p_4-...-(n-3)p_{n-1} = 2$$
I have no clue how to begin. Total degree = $2(n-1)$. Some how this will be used. And I have my suspicions on the absence of $p_2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, just solved it.

Let $S=p_1-p_3-2p_4-...-(n-3)p_{n-1}$.

Since total degree = $2(n-1)$,

$$\begin{align*}
&p_1+2p_2+3p_3+...+(n-1)p_{n-1}=2(n-1)\\\\
\implies&p_1+2p_2+4p_3-p_3+6p_4-2p_4+8p_5-3p_5+....+(2n-4)p_{n-1}-(n-3)p_{n-1}=2n-2\\\\
\implies&S+2(p_2+2p_3+3p_4+...+(n-2)p_{n-1}=2n-2\\\\
\implies&S+2(p_2+2p_3+3p_4+...+(n-2)p_{n-1}+2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} p_i=2n-2+2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} p_i\\\\
\implies&S+2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i.p_i=2n-2+2n\\\\
\implies&S+2(2(n-1))=4n-2\\\\
\implies&S=2\;.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

You already observed that $$\sum ip_i = 2(n-1).$$

But note also that $$\sum p_i = n$$

which is even simpler.

Could you could put the two equations together somehow?  You need to get $2$ on the right-hand side…

---

**Addendum**: Since OP solved the question, I'm going to post a detailed solution here for future reference.

OP has $$p_1 + 2p_2 + \cdots + (n-1)p_{n-1} = 2n-2\tag{A}$$ and wants to get something with 2 on the right.  One thing to try is to look for something like $$\sum\;?? = 2n\tag{B}$$ and then subtract A from B.

Moreover, for this to work, OP needs $\sum\;??  $ to be $2p_1 + 2p_2 + \cdots + 2p_{n-1}$ so that the left side of $B-A$ comes out to the expression $p_1-p_3-2p_4-\cdots-(n-3)p_{n-1}$ as required.  So in short, if we can prove

$$2p_1 + 2p_2 + \cdots + 2p_{n-1} = 2n$$

then we win.

But now that we see what we need to win, it's easy: $$\sum p_i = n$$ will do it. Even if OP didn't think of this before, it's obvious how to show this once you see what is needed.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think that many of your implications are if and only if... Thus, you can prove more generally the following: Let $G$ be any graph. Then $G$ satisfies the tree formula if and only if $p_1-p_3-2p_4-...-(n-3)p_{n-1} = 2$...In particular if $G$ has no cycles, or if G is connected or ... the $G$ is a tree if and only if....